# What is the difference between staload and #include in ATS?

Tags: ats

Both `staload` and `#include` can be used to load files in ATS:

```
staload "foo.dats"
#include "foo.dats"
```

Could someone tell me the difference between these two styles of loading files?

Answer (score 1):

`#include` copies the content of specified file into the current file. `staload` merely makes the names defined in the specified file available for the compiler, without copying.

Answer (score 0):

Note that staload can be written as #staload as well.

Also, please note that you currently cannot include a SATS file in a DATS file or a DATS file in a SATS file.